# How to hide a button in CSS Editor on homepage in Wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I basically wanted to know how I could remove the button in the top right of this website . I could not find the actual button within the CSS of the website, so I will have to result to this. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: Please post the code that you have done yet.

Comment: #genesisexpo_button_5dca4f5d12381 {
    display: none;
}

add this css to hide it

Comment: are you pertaining to the Get Ticket button at the top right of the header?

Comment: yes I am @denisey

Answer (score 1):

add this css to hide it

```
#genesisexpo_button_5dca4f5d12381 {
    display: none;
}
```

if you need to hide it on home page only please add bellow code

```
.home #genesisexpo_button_5dca4f5d12381 {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately i added it to the main method for the css and also the additional css in the customizer section and that did not work. Do you know where the proper placement of that code should be?

Comment: .home .header_button .genesisexpo_module_button a {
display: none;
}  can try this

Answer (score 0):

```
.home .header_button .genesisexpo_module_button a {
display: none;
}
```

can try this , this is only to hide on home page